# Powershell: is its regular expression the same regex in C# or linux shell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I learned some regular expression items in powershell, seems the content is a bit different from the regular expression I learned in C# or linux shell.

So is "regular express" a unique name of a expression type, or there're many kinds of implementations in the world that could all be called some kind of "regular expression languages"?

Comment: Would be best if you could add some examples of what you mean. Generally they are the same, the only difference I can think of is the way that options are provided to the regex engine and the escape characters that are used if you provide the regex as a string

Comment: [`get-help about_regular_expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az24scfc.aspx) shoiuld help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea in regular expressions is the same, no matter which environment you are using. The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is good overall introduction.

There are tons of different regex flavors. Some contain shortcuts, some extend the expressive powers. As some examples of shortcuts, [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) has `[:alnum:]` and `[:blank:]` which are the same as `[0-9a-zA-Z]` and `[ \t]`. The aim is to improve readability. There is a handy web site for [comparing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) different implementations.

About every modern implementation of regexes contain expansions that support non-regular language elements. Translating from a dialect to another might be untrivial a task, should expansions and shortcuts be used liberally.

A common caveat in Powershell is the dollar sign `$`. Normally it is the end-of-line anchor but Powershell uses it as a symbol for variable. This can be overcome with either escaping the dollar or using single quotes instead of double quotes.